# linked list biggest number

Tags: linked-list, integer, return, max

I am trying to retrieve the biggest number in a Linked List containing only integers.

If the list contains: 2, 67, 3, 9.

I want to return 67.

I'm having trouble visualizing and coming up with code that does this. Even a pseudo code would help.

Edit: I'm using Java to do this.

Comment: The pseudocode is: Iterate over the linked-list, keeping track of the largest value you've seen so far. When you reach the end of the list, return that value. (A lot of the details, such as how you iterate over the list, will depend on the language you're using and on how the linked-list is implemented. You haven't told us that stuff.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

- You need to traverse the whole list; you don't know in advance where the maximum is going to be.
- You'll need to carry some state while traversing: at any point, it may be the case that the rest of the list does not contain the maximum, and so you'll need to hang on to your current understanding of what it is.

So the general form of the pseudo-code will look like this:

1. Initialise the state that represents the maximum.
2. For each element in the list in turn: update the state, based on the element.

Lastly, you'll need to handle the edge cases: what does it mean to find the maximum of an empty Linked List?

To be more specific:

1. If the list is empty, return an error condition.
2. Let m, representing the current idea of the maximum, be the first element of the list.
3. For each remaining element of the list, if it is greater than m, set m to be the element.

At each point in the iteration, you have the invariant that m is the largest number so far in the list. When you are done, it must therefore be the largest number in the whole list.